# Set a session variable after one clicks on a link in node

Tags: node.js, express

So I have node generate

```
<a href="k">1</a>
<a href="k">2</a>
```

THEN

I want to save either one or two as a session variable depending on which is clicked. However I have no idea how to do this... = ( !

So, I suppose, how do views communicate with the controller. Does it have to be some sort of ajax call? [socket.io etc etc]

Comment: Which kind of framework are you using?

Comment: I am using express! but I am not sure that would make a difference?

Comment: Node.js does not manage sessions by itself, Express does.

Comment: OH! Sorry, I realize how my question was vague. = ) !

Comment: Yes, Also You can session variable by making an ajax call to expressjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can emit an event using socket.io on client side, and receive it in your server side then set your session variable.

Comment: For some reason I thought this would be the wrong way of doing it. I think I will go through with that though, thank you = ) !